# Unable to build a timeline chart from ajax values

Tags: javascript, timeline

Actually i'm trying to build a timeline chart using the google's one by using data passed from server side and received by ajax.

The problem is that i get the following error when i'm trying to do it:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Row given with size different than 4 (the number of columns in the table).
> ```

While here is what i get from the $.each cycle

[image]

As i'm just preparing the timeline with the data from ajax the real values will be set later while for now i'm just trying to add blank timelines by using the following [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501220/google-charts-api-add-blank-row-to-timeline?lq=1) so the data start and end should be the same.

here is the ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "prenotazioni.aspx/getTavolo",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $.each(msg.d, function (k, v) {
            //console.log(v);
            dataTable.addRow([[v, '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0)]]);
        });

    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**
That's what i'm trying to reach automatically from the ajax loop

[image]

The problem is that to make the cell blank the start and end date have to be the same but can't be the same for all the rows
here is how the following timeline was built

```
dataTable.addRows([
    ["33", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 2", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 3", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 4", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 5", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 6", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 7", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 8", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 9", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0)],
]);
```

So the issue now is how to make the start and end time same for row but different for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are trying to add a single row with only an element :

```
dataTable.addRow([[v, '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0)]]);
```

With this line, you are trying to add this data :

```
[
    [v, '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0)]
]
```

Which is only a single element (a list with a single list within), when you need 4 of them to make a complete row (it should contain 4 elements in your case).

Just remove the extra brackets and you should be fine :

```
dataTable.addRow([v, '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0)]);
```

**Edit :** The new error you are reporting in the comment (`Error: <text> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN"`) might be caused by the fact that the 2 dates you are giving are the same (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494158/error-in-timeline-chart-bar-text-attribute-x-expected-length-nan)).

**Edit 2 :** Following your edit :

As I said in my reply to your comments, the end date of a row can be the same as the start date of the next one. Try this :

```
dataTable.addRows([
    ["33", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 2", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 3", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 4", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 5", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 6", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 7", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 8", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0)],
    ["Tavolo 9", '', new Date(0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0), new Date(0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0)],
]);
```

Comment: Oh ok now i got another error and the chart is still not build: jsapi_compiled_ui_module.js:87 Error: <text> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".

Comment: yeah i was right now checking that answer, the problem is how can i set random data for each row but that the data will be same for start and end but different for each for?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want as an end result.

Comment: the start and end data have to be the same but as it cause error if all rows have same start and end data i have to set for each for different start and end data but start and end data have to be the same per row

Comment: like row1 start new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0) end new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0) row2 start new Date(0,0,0,13,0,0) end new Date(0,0,0,13,0,0)

Comment: The start and end date of the same row cannot be the same. The end point of a row and the start point of the next can be the same, though.

Comment: ok that's what i wrote in my question, the problem is that it's done by static way and i'm trying to create that rows from ajax in a loop and the data can be over 100, so i need to randomly set that data in someway

Comment: Then you should create another question. You asked a question with a scope, you should not change that scope, because it means other people cannot answer your question.